# Task for a Bamboo Build plan fails when trying to get information from packages

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, package, bamboo

I am trying to run an **MSBuild task** in atlassian bamboo for a test run of a Bamboo plan on my local device.  I have created the plan and it will retrieve the code from Github successfully, as well as being successfully running the default scoure control checkout.

The first problem I have is that the system will fail because the MSBuild task cannot get the referenced files.  So when I looked into the Manage Nuget Packages, It says some of the packages are missing, and when I click **Restore**  most of them restore but some of them have errors.

[image]

I think the main reason is because of this package **Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform -Version 1.0.0** is not being installed correctly. The error message says that it is because the path, file name or both are too long, but I have not named anything the project is already build and running successfully from Github.  I have tried to install as well by using the Package Manager Console but I get the same result.  I also tried creating the folders that it said the file was meant to be located but this is not working either.

I think that the problem is that the package is not found during package restore so I tried to add a NuGet.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
         <activePackageSource>
          <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
       </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

But this is not working how can I fix this?

Comment: After downloading this project from GitHub, please build it in Visual Studio directly, whether there has any error messages about could not find some nuget packages assemblies? In addition, please add the package sources under <activePackageSource> one by one, not use "All" to replace all sources. And where do you add this NuGet.Config file?

Comment: @wendy yeah the problem was I needed to add a private nuget package and then it would successfully download the correct packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message screenshot, the mentioned package "Carfinance.Authorization.Core.Mvc" is not found in nuget.org site. Please make sure this package's source URL has added into your Visual Studio NuGet Package Manager Source list (Tools -> Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package sources).

And please add the  node in the global NuGet.Config file which stored in C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\NuGet folder. After change the config file, please remember restarting your Visual Studio.

For the Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform path too long issue, please make sure the stored path folder is not too long. You could create a new project and store it on desktop and install this packages to check whether it could be install correctly. Then please copy your current project on desktop too, it could make sure its stored path will not too long.